# How to derive the font size from a height constraint?

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

I need to fix the height of a `Label` to a given number of pixels (calculated from the screen dimensions). To do so I would like to derive the font size (for a font family) which will allow my string to fit in that row.

The `.metrics()` method allows me to find the average height of a font (I think this is the height of the glyph `0`) but I do not believe this will help to determine the height of an arbitrary string.

Which `Tkinter` functionality could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tkFont.Font`, you can set the font size in pixels by making it negative:

```
tkFont.Font(..., size=-20)
```

So if you have a variable height for each Label derived from the screen dimensions (in pixels), you could just set the font to that variable:

```
tkFont.Font(..., size=-height)
```

This isn't a perfect solution, because unless your font is perfectly square, the pixel height will usually be greater than the pixel width for each character. Maybe a fixed width font has a ratio (ie, if pixel size of font is 6, height is 6*2), that you could take advantage of, but I don't think you can set the height of a font directly.

The other option would be to just assign the size of the Label to the pixel size directly, using a hack like giving it a blank image to make it register pixel size as width/height values:

```
root = Tk()

# derived width and height
width = 400
height = 40

# blank photo image
image = PhotoImage()

Label(root, image=image, compound='center', text='Hello World',
      width=width, height=height, bg='white').pack()

mainloop()
```

Or, a combination of the two:

```
root = Tk()

# derived width and height
width = 400
height = 40

# add a font
font = tkFont.Font(size=-height)

# blank photo image
image = PhotoImage()

Label(root, image=image, compound='center', text='Hello World',
      width=width, height=height, bg='white', font=font).pack()

mainloop()
```

Hope I understood correctly what you're trying to accomplish and this helps.